# SVG path animate from center, with mo-js

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to animate simple line shape of SVG using mojs's, `strokeDasharray` and `strokeDashoffset` maybe I'm confused with these properties and values it behaves strangely when animate.

The expected behavior is animation should start from the center and should grow both sides in one take till the end.

However, the animation starts from the middle of the line but stats with small segments and then final animation goes as expected - growing from the center and goes till the end.

I can't figure out why those small segments are coming at the beginning.

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/weerawansa/pen/EOVpmm)

> click on the page to see the animation on above link.

```
const line = new mojs.Shape({
    stroke: 'blue',
    shape: 'line',
    strokeLinecap: 'round',
    strokeDasharray: {'0%': '100%'},
    strokeDashoffset: {'-50%':'0%'},
    radius: 50,
    strokeWidth: 6,
    duration: 2000
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're looking for, the following code should do the job:

```
const line = new mojs.Shape({
  stroke: 'blue',
  shape: 'line',
  strokeLinecap: 'round',
  radius: {'0': '50'},
  strokeWidth: 6,
  duration: 2000
})
```

Properties like strokeDasharray are pretty challenging to work with, particularly if you're looking for precisely described animations.

Comment: One question. is it possible to with `strokeDashoffset` or `strokeDashoffset`? BCS Im gonna use this in complex SVG path.

Comment: Hi wimal, are you able to post an example of the complex path?